# Using Pandas to create, read, and update hdf5 file structure

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, pytables

We would like to be able to allow the HDF5 files themselves to define their columns, indexes, and column types instead of maintaining a separate file that defines structure of the HDF5 data.

How can I create an empty HDF5 file from Pandas with a specific table structure like:

Columns

- id (Int)
- name (Str)
- update_date (datetime)
- some_float (float)

Indexes

- id
- name

Once the HDF5 is created and saved to disk, how do I retrieve the column and index information without having to open the file completely each time since it will likely contain several GB of data.

Many thanks in advance...

-- UPDATE --

Thanks for the comments.  To clarify a bit more:

We do have *some* experience with Pandas but by no means are really proficient.  The part that is tripping us up is creating an empty data structure and reading that structure from a file that you will not want to fully open.  In all of the Pandas examples there is data.  The Pandas examples also only show two ways to retrieve data/structure which are to read the entire frame into memory or issue a where clause.  In this case, we would like to be able to see the table structure without query operations if possible.

I know this is an odd case.  Why the heck would you want an empty dataframe??  Well, we want to have a great deal of flexility in moving data around and want to be able to define a target dataframe structure prior to data writing, which could take place much later (e.g. hours or days).  Since the HDF5 specification maintains all that information it seems directionally incorrect to store the table structure information separately.  Thus our desire to crack the code on this subject.

-- UPDATE 2 --

To add more detail as @jeff requested.

We would like to abstract some of the common Pandas functions like summing data or merging two frames.  Thus we would like to be able to ask each frame what their columns are so we can present a view for the user to select the result frame columns.

For example, if we imported a CSV with columns A, B, C, D, and V and saved the frame to HDF5 as my_csv.hdf then we would be able to determine the columns by opening the file.

However, in our use case it is likely that the import frame for the CSV could be cleared periodically and no longer contain the data.  The reason knowing that the my_csv frame has certain columns and types is important because we want to enable a user to then select those columns for summing in a downstream operation.  Lets say a user wants to sum column V by the values in columns A and B only and save the frame as my_sum.  Since we can't ensure my_csv will always have data we would like to ensure it at least contains the structure.

Open to other suggestions obviously.  It is also possible to store the table structure info in the user_block.  This, again, is not ideal because the structure is now being kept in two different areas but I guess it would be possible to always update the user_block on save using the latest column and index information for the frame, although I believe the to_* operations in Pandas will blow away the user_block so...blah.  I feel like I'm talking myself into maintaining a peer structure definition but I REALLY would love some suggestions to not have to do that.

Comment: Have you read the [pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#hdf5-pytables) on HDF5? They're pretty thorough. You'll specifically want to look at the `table` format.

Comment: you can't create a completely empty file (this needs an enhancement to do this); create it on first use. You don't need to read the file to see the structure.

Comment: @Jeff has it, you don't need to read the several GBs (not giga bits) of data to navigate the structure.  According to the Pandas docs above, it uses PyTables to interface with the hdf file.  I've used hdf's A LOT and can suggest [h5py](http://www.h5py.org/), easy to use and structure comes in as a dictionary.  Performance in my instance was terrible with PyTables, probably 5 times faster with h5py.

Comment: @PlaidFan I don't think this is an odd case. But in general defining dtypes on a non-existant index is very tricky. You cannot ATM create a HDF pandas structure that is empty. As I said it can be done but a bit non-trivial. Maybe show what you want with data as an example.

Comment: To answer your first question. The HDF5 maintains its own meta-data; you don't need anything else to lookup and pull the data. You cannot change it onces its set however; though you can delete/copy the node and just start over. You should *not* treat a HDF5 as a standard database. It is amazingly fast at appending and reading. Updating/deleting is not nearly as efficient.

Comment: @Jeff Do you have any docs that show how we can set and get that meta-data.  I think that is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: why don't you create a frame with a single row, then remove that row? u can use ptdump -av file.h5 to see the structure

Comment: If I get you right you want a DDL, a schema defined outside the HDF5 file, but you want it inside th HDF5 file. I think your problem is architectural, not technological.

Comment: You mention in update 2 above that you want to get the columns and the only way is opening the hdf.  Are the columns known at the point of reading into the dataframe prior to writing to the hdf?  If so df.columns